# How to check visibility of the logo with cypress

Tags: cypress

I need to check the visibility of the logo of the page and the css is

< h6 class="MuiTypography-root jss10 MuiTypography-h6">IBC DASH

I wrote it like that but it didn't work

cy.get("MuiTypography-root jss10 MuiTypography-h6").should('be.visible')

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to query elements by class name in Cypress as it is coupled to a volatile thing such as styling.

You could do it by using `cy.get('[class="MuiTypography-root jss10 MuiTypography-h6"]')`, but I'd suggest you use `cy.contains('IBC DASH')`, `cy.get('h6')` or, if possible, you could add a `data-cy="logo"` to your element then use `cy.get('[data-cy=logo]')`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this element has three distinct classes. Therefor you have to call it either the way Daniel suggested with:

```js
cy.get('[class="MuiTypography-root jss10 MuiTypography-h6"]')
```

or with

```js
cy.get('.MuiTypography-root.jss10.MuiTypography-h6')
```